# How to get the value of a class member in HTML?

Tags: html

I'm trying to get a value in-between div tags, I've seen code that allows me to set the value of a textfield and use its value as a way of retrieving some information, but is there a fix to the way I'm trying to do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>...</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="number1">6</div>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>

        function print ()
        {
            var a = getElementByClassName ("number1").value;

            return a;
        }

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = now();
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: try `var a = getElementByClassName ("number1").innerHTML;`

Comment: The code works for me. i am not sure what's the problem. jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NikolaosG/oowt7hcu/

Comment: only `input`s have `value`, for other elements you can get values from innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call `getElementByClassName` which is not a function. It is `getElementsByClassName` which returns an array.

You can try something like this:

```
function print() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("number1")[0].innerHTML);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("number2")[0].innerHTML);

  return a+b;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = print();
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oowt7hcu/2/)